# Batch file to rename file and add sequence number to the file name

Tags: batch-file

I picked up the code below from another post.  I believe it should pick up the current directory folder and include it in the renaming part of the process, however that doesn't seem to work for me.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PUSHD "%~1"
set inc=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
set /a inc+=1
Echo Ren: "%%a" "%~n1!inc!%%~xa"
Ren "%%a" "%~n1!inc!%%~xa"
)
POPD
```

I have a .txt file that will be received into a folder each day named and time stamped.  Example as below:

`FileNameA_20170418153000.txt`

Essentially I'd like to amend the code above to rename the file: `filenam0001.txt` and continue to update the sequence number (which works perfectly well).

i.e.
`filenam0001.txt`
`filenam0002.txt`
`filenam0003.txt`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the leading zeros manually (add some zeros, then cut the last x characters):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set inc=0
for /l %%a in (1,1,50) do (
  set /a inc+=1
  set num=00000000!inc!
  set num=!num:~-5!
  echo !num!
)
```

Comment: @Stephen I've tried this and although the code executes there is no update made to the existing file.  To make sure I'm on the correct path can you tell me the purpose of the leading zeros?

Comment: the leading zeroes is what you wanted: `filenam0001.txt` etc. Shouldn't be too difficult to implement it to your code.

Comment: @Stephen That's what I thought.  You will need to accept my apologies as I'm relatively new to this.  If I refer back to the piece of code I used in my original post.  That code updates the name of the file to the sequence number i.e. 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on.  somehow I just need to add the text "Filenam" to the beginning of the file names that are being generated and the leading zero's to become "filenam0001.txt and so on.

Comment: how about `ren "%%a" "%~n1!num!%%~xa"`?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code in order to insert the leading zeros in a simple way...

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
PUSHD "%~1"
set inc=10000
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') DO (
   set /a inc+=1
   Echo Ren: "%%a" "%~n1_%%~na!inc:~1!%%~xa"
   Ren "%%a" "%~n1_%%~na!inc:~1!%%~xa"
)
POPD
```